# Workspace problem once the user name has been changed in TFS Source Control

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, tfs, version-control

For some reason the system admin changed my user name from XxXx to XxXx1 in the source control system. Then the problems started. I had to delete all local files and re-download them from source control just to open the project.

And after I had rebooted the computer, I can't do much to my files. Whenever I try to undo a checkout I get the following message:

> TF14098: Access Denied: User DOMAIN\XxXx needs UndoOther permission(s) for $/blablabla

So it is still trying to use my old user name. The user name and password is stored somewhere because I don't ever have to enter it when starting VS2008. Maybe through Explorer (I think I used it to browse to the tfs server and saved the user name and password).

Any tips?

Comment: I see Microsoft is still at it with their horrible magic version control stuff...

Comment: Haha... it's a big black box at times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After giving up on everything else, I deleted the local workspace and created a new one. Now everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

An option is to undo your changes as the Project Administrator and then re-check out those files (without a get) again under your new username. The first part is as if you are [un-doing changes of another user](http://dotnet.org.za/willy/archive/2008/07/23/tfs-undoing-a-checkout-of-another-user.aspx)

To unlock the files use the [tf.exe command line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z51z7zy0(VS.80).aspx)

```
tf undo "$/MyProject/VersionX/Utils/file.cs" /WORKSPACE:MaorDev;Domain\User  /server:MyServerName /recursive
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked to make sure that the Active Directory change has propagated to TFS?  I've seen issues before where users information is changed and TFS doesn't pick up the change and gets confused about your user.

Also take a look at the following blog post.  It details how to sync up TFS with a user name change in Active Directory

http://blogs.msdn.com/teams_wit_tools/archive/2007/03/15/handling-display-name-changes-in-team-foundation-server.aspx